# How to download in bash from zippyshare?

Tags: javascript, bash, curl, download, wget

Can anyone help me how to download files from zippyshare.com using bash (server with CentOS)?
Their download button made with flash, so i can't retrieve download link.

Comment: The `href` of the `dlbutton` is actually set by JavaScript. Look for  `document.getElementById('dlbutton').href` in the page source

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's definitely possible, but it's a little hacky. I've been doing it myself for quite some time using `wget`. The trick is to make the server think that the request is being made from a browser and to make that happen, you need a couple of things:

- The Download Link (The actual link to the file)
- Link Referrer (The webpage with the download button)
- Zippyshare Session ID (Found in Cookies)

Here's a screenshot explaining where you can get each item:

[image: Download From Zippyshare]

**Now open up your terminal, and use the following command (replacing necessary items):**

```
wget <download_link> \
--referer='<referrer>' \
--cookies=off --header "Cookie: JSESSIONID=<session_id>" \
--user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1'
```

**Example:**

```
wget http://www16.zippyshare.com/d/29887835/8895183/hello.txt \
--referer='http://www16.zippyshare.com/v/29887835/file.html' \
--cookies=off --header "Cookie: JSESSIONID=26458C0893BF69F88EB5743D74FE0F8C" \
--user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1'
```

Original answer: [How to use wget to download from hosting sites?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43542/41200)

*Note: In the command, it is in fact 'referer' not 'referrer'*

Answer (score 3):

Use Web developer tools from browser (IE/Chrome come with build-in, for Firefox use Firebug). Under network traffic tab look what HTTP request performed to download file.

Next step is to use **wget** or **curl** utility.

Reversing step is your task, make something by own...

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you give a try to PlowShare it can be found here

```
https://code.google.com/p/plowshare/
```

Example to download

```
plowdown http://www3.zippyshare.com/v/92458242/file.html
```

hope this helps. For more help https://code.google.com/p/plowshare/wiki/Readme4