# automating download of files with urllib2 and or wget

Tags: python, bash, cookies, urllib2, wget

I was trying to figure out how to download files from a web hosting site like zippy share. I saw this post [How to download in bash from zippyshare?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342359/how-to-download-in-bash-from-zippyshare/21100640#21100640) that shows how to use wget, and manually add in the cookie from the browser and add that to the header in wget. That works. But I want to use python, and get the cookie and then execute wget, so that I can do this programmatically(example: scraping a bunch of download links).

I came up with this hacky script to get the cookie and execute the wget command but it seems that the cookie is not good because I get a 302 redirect:

```
import urllib2, os
class HeadRequest(urllib2.Request):
    def get_method(self):
        return "HEAD"

url = "http://www67.zippyshare.com/d/64003087/2432/Alex%20Henning%2c%20Laurie%20Webb%20-%20In%20Your%20Arms%20%28Joy%20Kitikonti%20Remix%29%20%5bquality-dance-music.com%5d.mp3"
referer = "http://www67.zippyshare.com/v/64003087/file.html"
response = urllib2.urlopen(HeadRequest(url))

headers = response.info()
jcookieString = headers['Set-Cookie'].split(';')[0] #[11:]
# print headers
print "jcookie string " + jcookieString

wgetString = "wget " + url + " --referer=" + referer + " --cookies=off --header \"Cookie: " + jcookieString + "\"" + "--user-agent=\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1\""
os.system(wgetString)
```

I also tried using python's cookielib, but got the same behavior of the 302 redirect. Thanks.

EDIT: using requests here is the code now persisting the cookie that comes from the referer request because I am using the session to make the request...yet still no go:
looking at the response.history shows that the 302 redirect is still happening for some reason.

```
import requests

downloadUrl="http://www67.zippyshare.com/d/3278160/42939/Andre%20Nazareth%20-%20Bella%20Notte%20%28Original%20Mix%29%20%5bquality-dance-music.com%5d.mp3"
referer= "http://www67.zippyshare.com/v/3278160/file.html"
header={"user-agent": "\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1\"", 'referer': referer}
refererSession = requests.Session()
refererSession.get(referer)

downloadResponse = refererSession.get(downloadUrl, headers=header)
print downloadResponse.request.headers
print downloadResponse.status_code
if downloadResponse.status_code == 200:
    mp3Name = "song2.mp3"
    song = open(mp3Name, "wb")
    song.write(downloadResponse.content)
    song.close()
```

Comment: Have a look at the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies) module; it makes life _so_ much simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a system call from within python should really be left for situations where there is no other choice. Use the requests library, like so:

```
import requests
header={"user-agent":\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1\"",
'referer': referer}
cookies = dict(cookie_name='cookie_text')
r = requests.get(url, header=header, cookies=cookies)
```

If it doesn't work, maybe the settings itself aren't suitable for what you are trying to do. I am perplexed why you both set the cookie and have cookies=off in the wget statement.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. I had already done something similar by adding those headers using urllib2 and it didn't seem to work either. I'm not sure about the cookies=off either, gotta check and see if it's necessary.

Comment: Ok got it working with what you suggested, only issue is that I have to still copy paste the cookie from the browser window.